# "hadoop version" works but "sudo hadoop version" does not work

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I installed hadoop 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.  I followed instructions as in the link (I downloaded hadoop-2-7-1):

http://aqorn.com/resources/installing-singlenode-hadoop-2-2-0-on-ubuntu-virtualbox/

I have two issues:

(1) when I logout as hduser and update .bashrc file with hadoop env variables, I can run "hadoop version" to see version.  But I get error with "sudo hadoop version"  which is needed by a tool I want to run.
Please suggest what should I do.

(2) When I run the following:

Test Hadoop (Calculating the value of pi)
`$ cd /usr/local/hadoopenter`
`$ hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.1.jar`

Number of Maps  = 2
Samples per Map = 5

I get Java connection error.  But all installations went fine.

Please help on these issues.

Thanks,
ssarkar

Answer (score 0):

This is Adam, the guy who wrote the article. Glad you'r getting some value from the tutorial. The env vars won't be visible between sudo and non-sudo users. Try editing .bashrc file while logged in as the sudo user so it works either way.